# Leaks Instrument for Xcode doesn't work on Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, instruments

I'm trying to debug a serious memory leak on an iOS app I am developing. When I try to run the Leaks Instrument in Xcode (or any instrument for that matter) on my app running in a Simulator, I get "Activity monitoring service not available on this device." I'm running the latest version of Xcode & Instruments. Both are shown as Version 14.3. I have not found any information related to this error by scouring the Interwebs.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if Instruments has ever worked with iOS Simulators? I imagine it has in the past, otherwise why would "Simulators" appear in the Instruments dropdown list.